# Using Launchy gem to open a .gif using Preview on Mac and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have controller code which generates a .gif file and once it is generated, it needs to automatically open using Preview on a MacBook. On localhost, it works great, however on staging/production it does not. I've also tried saving the image to S3 and then pulling it from the public url that it provides but it doesn't print how we need it to, since it has to take up the full page (it's a shipping label being printed on a thermal printer).

Controller code:

```
path = Rails.root.join('tmp',customer.id.to_s+".gif").to_s
shipment.label(shipment.shipment_digest, path)     ## third party gem creates this image, saves it at the path
Launchy.open(path)  ### works great only on local
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

I also tried:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  region: 'us-east-1'
)

path = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object("shipping_labels/label_customer_#{customer.id}.gif")
shipment.label(shipment.shipment_digest, path.to_s)
obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object("shipping_labels/label_customer_#{customer.id}")
path.upload_file(path.to_s, acl:'public-read')
Launchy.open(path.public_url)
```

This opens in the image in a browser window and when it prints, it prints the entire page.

I should also note we're using Heroku.

Edit: I turned on Airbrake, now I'm seeing:

> Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new

Comment: What's the stack trace behind the 500 error? Where is your request going awry?

Comment: The Heroku logs haven't been much help, they're just showing a 500 error without any additional information. I've ran through it line by line in heroku rails console and it seems like that is where it stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of lunchy is to open an application on the computer where lunchy is being executed. That's why it works fine when you run the app on your own computer. You cannot use lunchy on Heroku; it makes no sense there. A Heroku server is not a Mac. Nor can lunchy remotely control other machines.

It sounds like what you want to do is have your Heroku app reach across the internet to a user's computer and force it to open the Preview app. That's not possible (not to mention a huge security hole).

The best you can do is indicate to the user's browser that you would like it to download the image file instead of displaying it inline. The user will then have to find the image in the downloads folder and open it. Depending on their computer's settings, it should open in the Preview app, but it might open something else like Photoshop; you can't control that.

In Rails a controller, use [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) to send the image as a download, like this:

```
send_file '/path/to.gif', type: 'image/gif', disposition: 'attachment'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I implemented the above send_file method and it works great